# How to plot histogram of a time series data using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a time series data on which I do some plotting using `pygal`. Here is how the data looks like

```
[(datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 20, 22, 195908, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 20, 25, 807185, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 20, 29, 566157, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 20, 33, 57685, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 54, 32, 3897, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 54, 35, 739188, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 54, 39, 592752, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 54, 43, 242095, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 52, 37, 311601, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 11.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 52, 40, 976424, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 11.0)]
```

Now I am able to do a regular `bar plot` using `pygal` but now I need to plot a `histogram`. I found out that `pandas` has a way to find `histogram` and plot it using `matplotlib`.

So here is what I did

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import  psycopg2

data = [(datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 20, 22, 195908, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 20, 25, 807185, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 20, 29, 566157, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 20, 33, 57685, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 54, 32, 3897, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 54, 35, 739188, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 54, 39, 592752, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 54, 43, 242095, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 12.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 52, 37, 311601, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 11.0), (datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 3, 0, 52, 40, 976424, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=330, name=None)), 11.0)]

df_hist = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data)).hist(bins=5)  // I divide the data into 5 buckets
plt.savefig('hist.svg')
```

But I encounter the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/souvik/Music/Test331.py", line 120, in <module>
    df_hist = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data)).hist(bins=5)
  File "/home/souvik/django_test/webdev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 2408, in hist_frame
    layout=layout)
  File "/home/souvik/django_test/webdev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_tools.py", line 238, in _subplots
    ax0 = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, 1, **subplot_kw)
  File "/home/souvik/django_test/webdev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1367, in add_subplot
    a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/souvik/django_test/webdev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py", line 60, in __init__
    ).format(maxn=rows*cols, num=num))
ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 0, not 1
```

However if I include the numeric value and exclude the `datetime` value from the data list, then I get the plot

```
data = [x[1] for x in data]
df_hist = pd.DataFrame(np.array(data)).hist(bins=5)
plt.savefig('hist.svg')
```

[image]

Now in the x axis, I wanted the time series range so I know the frequency of data under certain time interval. But I get the error as mentioned above when I include the original data.

How can I get a `histogram` of time series data? Also instead of relying on `matplotlib`, can I use `pygal` to do it?

**Note:** The figure above is on a much larger data. I have reduced the amount of data so as to post the question here.